# PlatformException when using Flutter share plugin to share files

Tags: android, flutter, dart, share, flutter-plugin

I'm trying to create an image from a widget and store it to a file. Then allow the user to share the image. We are using Flutter official share plugin:
https://pub.dev/packages/share

Here is my main logic:

```
  void _convertReportToImageAndShare() async {
    final RenderRepaintBoundary renderRepaintBoundary =
        _containerKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final image = await renderRepaintBoundary.toImage();
    final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
    final pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    final tempDir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
    final filePath = '$tempDir/image.png';
    final file = await File(filePath).create();
    file.writeAsBytesSync(pngBytes);
    await Share.shareFiles([filePath]);
  }
```

This function could be run successfully on a iOS simulator. However, when running on Android device, there is a PlatformException thrown:

```
The following PlatformException was thrown:
PlatformException(error, Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority
{my application id}.flutter.share_provider, null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority
{my application id}.flutter.share_provider
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:662)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:635)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:441)
    at io.flutter.plugins.share.Share.getUrisForPaths(Share.java:128)
    at io.flutter.plugins.share.Share.shareFiles(Share.java:69)
    at io.flutter.plugins.share.MethodCallHandler.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandler.java:42)
    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:738)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 )
 
 When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
 #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:582:7)
 #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:18)
 <asynchronous suspension>
```

I have checked the source code and the share_provider is defined in
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/share/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

How could I solve this problem? Do I need to modify something in AndroidManifest.xml? Thanks!

Comment: did you add the storage permission in android manifest ? what is the android version of device ?

Comment: Android version is 9. After added the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, the error still exists. Thanks!